# [C]redefinition of value?

Tags: c

I'm now working on a project and trying to organize the working code for later reproduction.
And then I encountered the famous redefinition error and unfortunately, none of the answers hit the spot.
So I simplified my problem and here it is.

```
//main.c
#include <iostream>
#include "main.h"
#include "myfunc1.h"

int func2();
int func3();
int func4();

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    func1();
    func2();
    func3();
    func4();
    
    return 0;
}

/* Trying to seperate func1*/

int func2(){
    int num2 = rep_val *2;
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<num2;i++){
    printf("HO!\n");
    }
}
int func3(int rep){
    int num3 = rep_val *3;
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<num3;i++){
    printf("HEY!\n");
    }
}
int func4(int rep){
    int num4 = rep_val *4;
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<num4;i++){
    printf("WHAT?\n");
    }
}
```

So, all I want to do is to spread each `func1,2,3,4` so `main.c` can remain clear.
And following `main.h , myfunc1.h, myfunc.c` are what I did for `func1`.

main.h

```
int rep_val = 4;// myfunc1,2,3,4 will use this value so placed here
```

myfunc1.h

```
#include "main.h"

int num1 = rep_val*2;//rep_val = 4

int func1();
```

myfunc1.cpp

```
#include <myfunc1.h>

int func1(){
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<num1;i++){
    printf("HI!\n");
    }
}
```

And the error was

```
D:\DEV\DEV C\Header_practice\main.h [Error] redefinition of 'int rep_val'
```

What am I missing? I've looked for several relevant queries and still can't find solution.
Any word from you will be appriciated.
Thanks!

Nam Jeongkuk

Comment: Don't put code like `int rep_val = 4;` or `int num1 = rep_val*2;` in a header file.

Comment: `main.h` file was called in `main.c` which contains `rep_val` already, but `myfunc1.h` also contains the variable declaration code for `rep_val`, so I guess it's what you're missing and the conflict took place.

Comment: Do you have include guards in your headers? Otherwise `main.h` will be included twice and the variable definition will also be included twice.

Comment: Now I'm getting the picture of a compile process and solve the simplified problem.
__HEADER_GUARD__, 'extern' were the keys. Thanks Weather Vane, Rohan Bari. And thanks for the additional help like where a variable should be Gehardh. So much appriciated. bb

Comment: `#include <iostream>`!!! ?? Is this C, or C++?

Comment: Oh It meant to be C but the template was C++. Honest mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add a header guard to `main.h` and `myfunc1.h` and make variable definitions extern (turn them into declarations).

main.h:

```
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__

extern int rep_val;

#endif
```

myfunc1.h:

```
#include "main.h"

#ifndef __MYFUNC1_H__
#define __MYFUNC1_H__

extern int num1;

int func1();

#endif
```

Alternatively, the `#ifndef` `#define` `#endif` sequences can be replaced by `#pragma once` with the most important compilers.

And then you add the variable definitions to the corresponding c files.

main.c:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "main.h"
#include "myfunc1.h"

int rep_val = 4;// myfunc1,2,3,4 will use this value so placed here
...
```

myfunc1.c:

```
#include <myfunc1.h>

// Cannot initialize this variable with other
// variable value. Can only provide default.
// Be aware of race conditions!
int num1 = 0;

int func1(){
    // but can update this variable from within function
    num1 = rep_val*2; //rep_val = 4
    ...
}
```

However, it is not regarded as good practice to place variables in file scope if not really necessary. Therefore i would suggest e.g. to put the `num1` definition in the function `func1` and remove it from the header at all.
You may think about your context and where to place your variable definitions. If you have a good reason to provide a file scope variable then you'd go. The same may apply for `rep_val`.

Comment: Thanks. You showed me where to start off and after several google search, finally solve the simplified problem. Now I'll be working on the project and hoping I can manage it. Much appreciated pqans. bb

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the statement

```
 int num1 = rep_val*2;
```

cannot reside on file scope, it has to be in a function scope (for the platform to know when to execute it). This instance of `rep_val` is seen as it's own definition, which conflict with the other one in the other translation unit.

That said, without a header guard, you have multiple inclusion, which creates multiple definition of the same variable. Do not define the variables in header files, declare them in header file and define them in one of the translation units.

Comment: Thanks! Aside from the main problem you gave me an idea where a variable should be. And just another question. I thought 'main.h' is the best place to declare and define extern value and after all, it worked. Like,

extern int rep_val;
int rep_val = 4;

in main.h.
And you said don't. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Otherwise, without header guard, you'll face problems like this one. :) Keep variable declarations in header file and definition in source files.

Comment: Ah Yeah. Make sense. Thanks Sourav Ghosh. bb